# How to return a DECIMAL(4,0) in TEXT keeping the 0000 format?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I want to return in a Stored Function a value as TEXT but I want to be `0001`, and not `1`

I have this code fragments:

```
DECLARE _RESTRICTEDROUTE DECIMAL(4,0);

RETURN(_RESTRICTEDROUTE);
```

I tried

```
RETURN(CAST(_RESTRICTEDROUTE AS TEXT));
```

but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`LPAD()`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

This should work:

```
RETURN(LPAD(_RESTRICTEDROUTE, 4, "0"))
```

Comment: I need to the value 4 from the DECLARE, sometimes will be 3, othertimes 2. Is there some other way to use this on global bases? CAST/CONVERT doesn't work in SPs?

Comment: @Pentium the `4` value is the maximum *possible* number of digits, so I think a CAST will never left-pad the necessary zeroes. It might be possible to get the value from the schema table somehow, but it's likely to be complicated

Comment: check this other question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213973/how-to-get-the-dimension-of-a-declared-variable-in-sps